# Compiles-to-HTML with Pythonic respect for whitespace

Tags: html

A few days ago someone I met showed me this language that compiles to HTML the same way that Coffeescript does to Javascript, but this language has the same level of respect for whitespace that Python does, though it's for HTML.

The code sample I saw looked something like this:

```
- html
    - head
        - title
            This is the title.
    - body
        - h1
```

etc.

Anyone know what it might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)?

The example from their site is:

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= pageTitle
    script(type='text/javascript')
      if (foo) {
         bar()
      }
  body
    h1 Jade - node template engine
    #container
      if youAreUsingJade
        p You are amazing
      else
        p Get on it!
```

which becomes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Jade</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if (foo) {
        bar()
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Jade - node template engine</h1>
    <div id="container">
      <p>You are amazing</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```